# Power BI report integration with Razor Pages

Tags: powerbi, razor-pages

I want to integrate PowerBI report with my Razor Pages Application which uses a standalone login authentication(No connection with Active Directories).

I have a copied the Embed Source code from PowerBI site and used in my webapplication. But when i access my page its showing like this

[image]

Is there anyway to bypass this login authentication and display the dashboard to everyone even if they dont have powerbi account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a publicly available report. You need to use the publish to web feature. This feature needs to be enabled (if not already) in your tenant level settings. [There is a great write up here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/heads-up-the-publish-to-web-default-is-changing-and-it-affects-who-can-create-public-embed-codes/).

[image]

[image]